# ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found when dismissing from BottomSheetDialogFragment for ComposeView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-lifecycle, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have a `ComposeView` for a particular view that is within an XML layout for a view holder. This is shown as a list of items in a fragment.

On this screen, when a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` shows, then dismisses, the view holder items change and are rebinded and then I get a crash.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView{cfc51a6 V.E...... ......ID 21,156-1059,642 #7f0a03f9 app:id/product}
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.addView (ComposeView.android.kt:349)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.createLifecycleAwareWindowRecomposer (WindowRecomposer_android.kt:349)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.createLifecycleAwareWindowRecomposer$default (WindowRecomposer_android.kt:324)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerFactory$Companion$LifecycleAware$1.createRecomposer (WindowRecomposerFactory.java:168)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerPolicy.createAndInstallWindowRecomposer$ui_release (WindowRecomposerPolicy.java:224)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.getWindowRecomposer (WindowRecomposer_android.kt:299)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.resolveParentCompositionContext (ComposeView.android.kt:242)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.ensureCompositionCreated (ComposeView.android.kt:249)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.createComposition (ComposeView.android.kt:194)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.setContent (ComposeView.android.kt:420)
```

I'm using fragment navigation component, and when I change the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` destination in the nav graph from `<dialog>` to `<fragment>`, then it works (although the dialog isn't a bottom sheet anymore).

I have appcompat and fragment-ktx dependencies updated to their most stable version. The fragment is hosted by an appcompat activity.

This seems to only happen when dismissing that bottom sheet dialog and items are rebinded. When I rebind items normally (when you have a long list and you scroll up and down), this crash doesn't occur.

`ViewCompositionStrategy` is set to `DisposeOnDetachedFromWindowOrReleasedFromPool`.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Have you read the release notes for [RecyclerView 1.3.1-rc01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview#recyclerview-1.3.1-rc01)? Have you tried upgrading to that version?

Comment: Upgrading the recycler view dependency worked. Thanks ianhanniballake