# IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from android.widget.FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `ComposeView` in a recyclerview item.
On the `onBindViewHolder` of `RecyclerView.Adapter` I am calling `setContent` on the `ComposeView`.

Sometimes this leads to this crash.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found from android.widget.FrameLayout{cf04e92 VFE...C.. ......ID 0,599-1768,808 #7f0b05f5 app:id/root_container}
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.createLifecycleAwareViewTreeRecomposer(WindowRecomposer_android.kt:244)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.access$createLifecycleAwareViewTreeRecomposer(WindowRecomposer_android.kt:1)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerFactory$Companion$LifecycleAware$1.createRecomposer(WindowRecomposerFactory.java:99)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposerPolicy.createAndInstallWindowRecomposer$ui_release(WindowRecomposerPolicy.java:155)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.getWindowRecomposer(WindowRecomposer_android.kt:230)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.resolveParentCompositionContext(AbstractComposeView.java:244)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.ensureCompositionCreated(AbstractComposeView.java:251)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.createComposition(AbstractComposeView.java:196)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.setContent(ComposeView.java:426)
       at a.b.c.f.s.viewholders.S.bind(S.java:154)
       at a.b.c.f.f.RvAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ForYouRvAdapter.java:48)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7337)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6194)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6460)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1631)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3686)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27720)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:811)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:466)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:134)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:278)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:120)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1594)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1708)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27720)
       at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1792)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:627)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27720)
       at androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onMeasure(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:705)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27720)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7352)
       at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
       at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:833)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27720)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7352)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27720)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.measureChildWithMargins(RecyclerView.java:9681)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1657)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4578)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24969)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
       at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onLayout(ViewPager2.java:527)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24969)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24969)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24969)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
       at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1213)
       at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:899)
       at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:919)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24969)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24969)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.layoutDecoratedWithMargins(RecyclerView.java:9878)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1689)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4578)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24969)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
       at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onLayout(ViewPager2.java:527)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24969)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24969)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24969)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24969)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24969)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24969)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24969)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:1432)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:24969)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6784)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:4917)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:4240)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:3116)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:10885)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1301)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1309)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:923)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:852)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1283)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

Using `androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.1.1`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76410642/viewtreelifecycleowner-not-found-when-dismissing-from-bottomsheetdialogfragment for a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem to work to upgrade to androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.1. see [release notes for 1.3.1-RC1](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview#recyclerview-1.3.1-rc01)

I found it in the comments in this stack overflow question: [ViewTreeLifecycleOwner not found when dismissing from BottomSheetDialogFragment for ComposeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76410642/viewtreelifecycleowner-not-found-when-dismissing-from-bottomsheetdialogfragment)